# bash: [: 1+1: integer expression expected

Tags: linux, bash

I have a main directory with 40 subdirectories with names `[Set 1]`, `[Set 2]` ... `[Set 40]`, each containing 20 wallpapers with name `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ... `20.jpg`. I want to move all these wallpapers to the main directory and rename them as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` ... `800.jpg`. I wrote the following Bash script but getting error.

```
i=1; j=1; k=1;
while [ $i -ne 41 ]; do
  j=1;
  while [ $j -ne 21 ]; do
    mv \[Set\ $i\]/$j.jpg $k.jpg;
    j=$j+1;
    k=$k+1;
  done;
  i=$i+1;
done
```

```
bash: [: 1+1: integer expression expected
bash: [: 1+1: integer expression expected
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: If you're using bash 3+, you can use ranged for loop instead of while - safer and easier.

Comment: @MatthewRock in what way is that safer ?

Comment: @123: Prevents off-by-one errors.

Comment: @choroba how does it?

Comment: @123: `i in {1..10}` is clear. `((i = 1; i <= 10; i++))` is less clear (at least for people not programming in C-like languages for ages).

Comment: @choroba You are comparing two for loops... MatthewRock was comparing the `while` with `for`. I still disagree about your above point anyway, i think both are perfectly clear after a one second explanation.

Comment: @123 after seeing an example you still can't see it? For encapsulates (a bit) that you want to go through the range of numbers. While is more general in this concept. For prevents some errors(off-by-one error). Also the problem with this program was (partially) caused by using while - while incrementing value yourself, you need to know how to do it - ranged for loop does it for yourself. This has other benefit where you don't predict some branch correctly and end up in infinite loop.

Also, imagine much longer code - you need to read a lot more to see it's just a for, written by yourself.

Comment: @MatthewRock so it's easier, not safer in any way. You can't say something isn't safe and use the reasoning "people don't know how to do it"

Comment: @123 Preventing errors means it's safer. It's safer in the same way as smart pointers, encapsulation, bounds checking or strong typing. If something makes it less likely that you will make an error, it **is** safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash you enclose mathmatical/arithmetical operations in `$(())`, so

```
i=1; j=1; k=1; 
while [ $i -ne 41 ]; do 
    j=1
    while [ $j -ne 21 ]; do 
        mv "[Set ${i}]/${j}.jpg" $k.jpg
        j=$(($j+1)) k=$(($k+1))
    done
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Should do what you want..

Comment: Or simpler `((j++, k++))` and `((i++))`.

Comment: or even `while (( i++ != 41))` and skip the bottom incrementer.

Comment: Just to note, the answer as stands is also POSIX-compliant; the comments suggest `bash`-specific extensions.